# Prototypes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

In the JavaScript the same thing you can do in many different ways.

Consider the examples:

1:

```
function Circle(radius) {
 return {
  "r" : radius,
  "area" : function(){
   return Circle.pi * this.r * this.r; 
  }
 }
}
Circle.pi = 3.14159;

var a = Circle(10);
alert(a.area());
```

2:

```
function Circle(radius) {
    this.r = radius;
}

Circle.pi = 3.14159;
Circle.prototype.area = function(){
 return Circle.pi * this.r * this.r; 
}

var a = new Circle(10);
alert(a.area());
```

The second is better than first because we dont define the same function *area* for any instance of the *Circle*.

But lets consider 
3:

```
function Circle(radius) {
 return {
  "r" : radius,
  "area" : Circle.area
 }
}
Circle.pi = 3.14159;
Circle.area = function(){
 return Circle.pi * this.r * this.r; 
}

var a = Circle(10);
alert(a.area());
```

Is there any reason to prefer second style instead of third? Or I misunderstood something at all?

Comment: You know about the availability of [`Math.PI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/PI), don't you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object oriented javascript with prototypes vs closures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564238/object-oriented-javascript-with-prototypes-vs-closures)

Comment: I've made some benchmarks like here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kristoffer/archive/2007/02/13/javascript-prototype-versus-closure-execution-speed.aspx. 
The result - the 3rd style just between 1st and 2nd :)
Thx for all answers and comments, I've learnt a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would definitely go with example 2. Neither example 1 or 3 make good use of JavaScript's object-oriented features because:

1. You duplicate method definitions in each instance.
2. By returning a new object instead of using `this`, you lose the identity of the class, i.e. you can no longer do checks like `a instanceof Circle`.
3. You give up the possibility of inheritance since you do not use prototypes.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any reason to prefer second style instead of third?

The third style is still wasting a *small* amount of space in order to store the association between the name `area` and the area function.

Also because you are returning a new `Object` from the `{...}` literal, `instanceof Circle` won't work.

> The second is better than first because we dont define the same function area for any instance of the Circle.

Indeed, but it can *sometimes* be useful to define a new copy of each method—a copy that, thanks to closures, can know what object it is bound to. With traditional prototyping you only get the `this` context which is set from the object the caller retrieved it from, rather than bound to a particular object. The first way avoids the problems of `this`-retention in things like event handlers, at the price of some loss of efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `Circle.prototype.area` and `Circle.area` is that one is only accessible with a instance of the class.

```
Circle.prototype.area = function(){};
Circle.area // wrong
(new Circle()).area // ok (you need a Circle object)
```

and

```
Circle.area = function(){};
Circle.area // ok (you don't need the object, its static)
(new Circle()).area // wrong
```

Comment: Not entirely true. The following is legal: `Circle.prototype.area()` (although you probably want to use `call` or `apply` with it.)

Comment: True, but if it's on prototype generally it shouldn't be called like that, it might depend on some properties of the instance. Anyway thanks for point that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with example 2 is, that when you accidentally forget to use the `new` operator when creating the object, and just call `var a = Circle(10);` (which is fine for the 3rd example, but not for the 2nd), then your constructor creates big trouble:

```
this.r = radius;
```

Since you didn't use `new`, `this` will be assigned the global object, so the constructor really sets the global variable `r`!

So I would strongly prefer example 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to comment on "The second is better than first because we dont define the same function area for any instance of the Circle." In practice, this may be such a negligable advantage as to be totally insignificant. I tend to favor syntax and human-friendly code over efficiency, **unless performance is noticably affected**. I've been completely ignoring the Prototype feature of javascript and also avoiding the use of "this", basically using technique #1. It's working just fine for me. I find avoiding "this" prevents a lot of confusion about just what "this" refers to. It's perfectly possible to create inheritance-type structures without "prototype". You simple create a superclass object, and override whichever methods you want. Douglas Crockford has written pretty extensively on numerous different ways to do inheritance in javascript.

I will agree with casablanca above that being able to test for type using "instanceof" is a nice advantage of returning "this". Perhaps I'll take another look at "protype" and "this" on a future project. For now, though, I'm getting along just fine without them.

Comment: Regarding `this`: also read Peter Michaux' [JavaScript Widgets Without "this"](http://michaux.ca/articles/javascript-widgets-without-this)